# User select date 10 years from today date jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, datepicker

Working on jquery date picker in my current code. I want the datepicker should show from the year 1900 - till today date User has to select previous 10 years from today date if in case user select yesterday date or today 's date or a month ago date eror msg should populate in the error message field

Here is my current Jquery code

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '-115:+1M'
    }).on('change',function(){
        alert("check");
    });
 });
```

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/4t5zhenn/)

Kindly help me

Thanks & Regards
Mahadevan

Comment: _user has to select 10years from today date_ isn't this should be done automatically on calculation of current date IMHO that would be better ux.

Comment: before 10 years or after 10 years?

Comment: user has to select before 10years

Comment: Explain clearly. from before 10 years to current year or all the years should be before 10 years? from which year to which year you need?

Comment: @Rajeshkannan sorry for that actually I want the datepicker should show from the year 1900 - till today date but if user has to select 10 years from today date if in case the user select yesterday date or today 's date or a month ago date eror msg should populate

Comment: So why if a user needs to select a future date do you want the dates to start from 1900?

Comment: I don't want user needs to select the future date user has to select previous 10years from today date

Comment: ok got it check my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/32452840/2006386

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do all the calculations in the `onSelect:fn(){}` provided by the the datepicker itself. You can get the selected value from the function's param name of your choice, i have given it the name `date`. Now when you get the date from here you can convert it to a dateObject to extract the year from it, same way you need to get the current year with a new date object.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '-115:+0M',
    onSelect: function(date) { // bind the builtin onSelect event
                               // which gets you the selected date
      var selYear = new Date(date).getFullYear(); // get the full year of selected date 
      var currYear = new Date().getFullYear(); // get the current year

      if ((currYear - selYear) > 10) { // check in the if conditon for 10 years
        $('#display_error').html('You should choose dates from last 10 years only.');
        this.value='';
      }
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>
<label id="display_error" class="display_error"></label>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i have to show the year from 1900 - current date but user has to select previous 10 years from today date

Comment: may i ask why? because just show 10 years to have a limited scope of error in choosing a date.

Comment: as per the scope of my current work is i have to show the user till today date :) but the field should accept 10 years back from today date

Answer (score 2):

ok Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bxh5eq1f/

It is **WORKING**

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '-115:+1M',
            maxDate:new Date(),
        }).on('change',function(){
            today = new Date();
            tenYearBefore = new Date().setYear(new Date().getFullYear() -10);
            selected = new Date($(this).val());
           if(selected>tenYearBefore) {
            $(".display_error").show();   
           } else {
               $(".display_error").hide();
           }
        });
  });
```

let me know if it is worked

Comment: it was working fine but one small query is that possible the provided future dates can be disabled

Comment: yeah you can by maxdate:new Date()

Comment: I have updated my above code and the jsfiddle link also check now